# Why am I unable to add my PCL to my Universal App?

Tags: portable-class-library, win-universal-app

I get "Unable to add reference" when I try to add my PCL as reference. The projects are in the same solution. The error message doesn't say anything more.

When I try to add the .dll via `Browse...` I get the an error telling me that I can not add a PCL targeted at `.NET Framework` to a project targeting `.NETCore`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that your PCL is targeted at `.NET Framework` and not `.NETCore`. `.NETCore` does only contain a subset of `.NET Framework`.

To solve this, replace your PCL project with a `Class Library (Portable for Universal Apps)`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the library you think is a PCL is not actually a Portable Class Library.  It's just a .NET Framework library.

Try creating a new PCL and referencing that.  See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for information on how to create a PCL.